# I'm getting an identifier expected error

Tags: java

I am trying to write a simple quiz game.

Trying to lay out one question and answer session with this code sample:

```
QuizCard(q, a){   
  String question = "What's the name of the lead actor in the movie 'I Robot'?";
  String answer = "Will Smith";

  q = question;
  a = answer;
 }
```

QuizCard is a constructor but I am getting an identifier expected error. Could someone make me understand what I am doing wrong here please.

Comment: q and a are supposed to have types in the argument of the method.

Comment: Why are you changing the constructor parameters?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new `quizcard`? or defining the constructor? the first is done with `new QuizCard("What's the name...", "Will Smith")`, the second is done with user2548635's comment

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error because you are not specifying the parameter types. Also your constructor isn't doing anything because only the local variables are being changed. Sounds like what you really want is something like this:

```
public class QuizCard {
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public QuizCard(String question, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
QuizCard(String q, String a){
    String question = "What's the name of the lead actor in the movie 'I Robot'?";
    String answer = "Will Smith";
    q = question;
    a = answer;
}
```

Note: You missed to provide **identifier** which means the type of parameter that you want to provide in the constructor. The constructor doesn't know whether you are passing a **String** or **int** or **double**.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful because it doesn't provide a correct constructor.

Comment: could you tell what is correct constructor?  We can't change the business logic of someone.. We are here to correct his technical mistakes only, not his business logic!!

Comment: This answer is correct.  The fact that the OP needs more help than they've actually asked for is not the respondent's fault.